# Using new window instead of web-workers

Tags: javascript, performance, web-worker

Since I've tried out webworkers for the first time I'm struggling to find a real use case for them. Communication with them isn't as easy as just passing objects or references, they don't have a window object so I can't use JQuery and the increased complexity of building an interface is not worth the load saved on the main thread. So all the options I'm left with are basically working through large arrays to gain a performance advantage.

Today I thought about opening a new window by `window.open()` and use the newly created window object to do some task and pass the result back to the main window. I should even be able to access the DOM of the main window by accessing the `window.opener`variable in the new window.

### My questions are:

- Is that really going to give me a performance advantage?
- Are there any caveats about this idea besides more complicated debugging?
- Can I access the DOM of the main window from the new window using the `window.opener` variable and take the load of creating new DOM elements from the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that really going to give me a performance advantage?

No, as long as you can access `window.opener` or access objects from one tab to another, that means they share same instance of javascript interpreter, and javascript interpreter is single-threaded.

There is literally no (practical) way around this. You either have separate thread, or share same objects.

> Are there any caveats about this idea besides more complicated debugging?

Main caveat: it does not work. Also caveat: separate window is probably not something suitable for production.

> Can I access the DOM of the main window from the new window using the `window.opener` variable and take the load of creating new DOM elements from the main thread?

You can, but you should probably use correct document instance for calling `document.createElement`.

> So all the options I'm left with are basically working through large arrays to gain a performance advantage.

That's exactly what workers are for, unless you are processing large amount of raw data, they are probably not a solution to your problem.

---

If you have performance drops when creating DOM nodes, you're most likely doing something wrong. Remember that:

- `createDocumentFragment` exists for creating self contained element groups before appending them.
- `innerHTML` causes DOM to rebalance tree in which you cahnged the HTML
- `new Text` or `document.createTextNode` can be used to fill in text without `innerHTML`
- If your page is scrollable table of many items, only those on screen need to be rendered.

You should also profile your code using developper tools to see where is the performance bottleneck. WebWorker is for data processing (eg. resizing images before upload), not for DOM manipulation.

Final note: it's the end of 2019, "*I can't use jQuery*" shouldn't be a problem any more. We now have `document.querySelector` and CSS animations, which were main uses of jQuery in the past.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently trying to improve performance of creating around 180k markers on a leaflet map. I need to categorize the markers at first to show custom marker-icons and then create them on my leaflet element. I was hoping to offload that process to a web-worker but `L` requires a window object and the array iteration is just one of severeal bottlenecks.
I'll take a look at `Document.createDocumentFragment()` though.

Comment: @wuha You should first look into filtering the data. Nobody (=none of your users) can simultaneously process 180k markers. Maybe you should only create those that are visible on the current map's zoom and pan? Merge those that are close to each other when the map is zoomed out? Or you could convert them into heatmap. All those three things are already something a webworker is good for - bunch of numbers in, bunch of numbers out.

Comment: I already use the leaflet markercluster plugin to cluster nearby markers (I think you could call that a heatmap). Still, the processing of markers in the first place takes quite some time but offloading just that is not worth the trouble.